# Android Image Assets (Icon) not Showing on Some Phones

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have added a new Image Asset to my build, tested it on virtual and physical devices, then pushed as a Beta to the Play Store.  Everything is checking out on my end, but one of my testers is saying that the app icon is not showing up!?  He's using a Google Pixel phone running Android 8.0.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Oreo requires few versions of your icon, and you have to create adaptive icon
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Select app folder from your project
2. Select File → New → Image Asset
3. On "Foreground Layer" choose the path of your image and resize in order to get the proper aspect for the icon
4. On “Background Layer" use the provided background color
5. Click on Finish and mipmap icons are created in different sizes

In your manifest file do the following changes


 <application
    ...
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    ...>
</application>
```

Source: [How to create adaptive icons for android](https://dev.to/_s_farias/how-to-create-adaptive-icons-for-android-using-android-studio-459h)